# autocomplete function is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, autocomplete

I am having the list of names inside a string in a JSP page.
and **I want to show the data in the name field by autocomplete function**
but i am unable to get that.

```
<%
String  Auto_Complete_Name=// I AM GETTING LIST OF VALUES BY SESSION 
%>

script>
    $(function() {
        var name=[<%=Auto_Complete_Name%>];
        $( "#Name" ).autocomplete({
            source: name
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want to **show list in this field**.

```
        <s:form name="search_Details" id="search_Details">    

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sim-4 control-label"><s:text name="Name" /></label>
        <div class="col-sim-6">
           <input type="text" id="Name" placeholder="Name" name="Name" class="form-control"  size="17"  >
        </div>
    </div>

</s:form>
```